# Locating a link using href text and a stored variable

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Using `C#` and Selenium Webdriver, I am attempting to locate an `href` that contains an auto-generated id.

In my automation script, I have stored this value in a variable called `_studentId`

What I would like to do is

1. locate the `href` that contains the same id value is the value stored in the _studentId variable and
2. click the link.

Here is a sample of the page source with the `href` and the Id value. Note: the Id value will change so I need to identify the link based not just on the `href` value but also using the dynamic Id value which will be the same as in my `_studentId` variable. The portion that contains the value `333795` is the section that matches the `_studentId` variable.

```
<td class="score input input-blue">
     <a title="Test Result" size="340,300" class="frameDialog" href="/Body/Students/Enrollment/EdStudentInfo.aspx?Id=333795&amp;Pn=0&amp;tp=2">
          <span style="text-decoration: underline">None</span>
     </a>
</td>
```

The following code will click the link but I need to better identify the link using the `_studentId` variable as there will be many links with the same text but with different Student ID values.

```
IWebElement testResultsLink = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("[href*='Body/Students/Enrollment/EdStudentInfo.aspx']"));
testResultsLink.Click();
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add the the variable you are storing before to the selector

```
"[href*='Body/Students/Enrollment/EdStudentInfo.aspx?id='" + _studnetID + "']"
```

or simply use the xpath pointing to `a` tag containing the id

```
"//a[contains(@href,'" +_studnetID + "')]"
```

Comment: Hi Saifur - I modified my code to match your first example. However, this is not working for me.IWebElement testResultsLink = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("[href*=Body/Students/Enrollment/EdStudentInfo.aspx?Id="+_studentId+"]"));
                testResultsLink.Click();   I next tried the second option. The result is that the object is located but it is not the correct object.                 IWebElement testResultsLink = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[contains(@href," + _studentId + ")"));

Comment: I next tried to record the object using Selenium IDE. here is the code that the was recorded using Selenium IDE:              driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//tr[@id='333781']/td[6]/a/span")).Click(); Is there a way to modify this code so that the value of the id is replaced with the _studentId variable?

Comment: Yes you should be able to do `driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//tr[@id='" + _student + "']/td[6]/a/span"));`

Comment: I believe my code was missing `'` before and after the `_studentId` variable. Edited try it now and let me know if that works

Comment: Hi Saifur - The revised XPath code works. Thanks Again.driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//tr[@id='" + _student + "']/td[6]/a/span"));

Comment: Have this answer met your need? Is there anything else I can do to help you out with this question?